# unity 5.4 apk installed but won't open

Tags: unity-game-engine, apk

Okay, so basically I build my game in unity, saved it in a folder and drag the file in a folder on my phone, made sure unknown source was checked and installed it on my phone.

However when I open it it shows the unity splash page but then it closes for some reason I do not know, I searched it up tried all different resources but nothing worked, it still did the same thing, I tried it out on my brother's mobile and it worked fine for him (it didn't close and it let him play my game).

It just doesn't work on mine. I'm using **unity 5.4**

Can anyone help me with this problem?

**Okay problem has returned agian**

Thank you. :)

Comment: Most likely your phone has not enough memory.

Comment: no, I have a SD card with 7.39GB and my app is only 40MB

Comment: You have to post the crash log from your Android app. Also what what Android device that is and the Android OS.

Comment: @Programmer. I have a HTC desire 610 and my OS is Android 4.4.2 kitkat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to uninstall all the previous version of the app from your Phone and then try to re-install it.

If the above plan didn't work, Change the build settings in Unity from Prefer External to Automatic,

I hope this will help you...

Comment: Sorry, you suggestion didn't worked. But thank you for your suggestion. :)

Answer (score 0):

my problem got resolved by deleting the android manifest file and then building again.

I hope this will help for people like me in future.

P.S : for me manifest was located at plugins/android/androidmanifest.xml